# TFF: finetune with pretrained network : Test accuracy still constant after all rounds

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I would like to Fine-tune the pre-trained model  with Federated Learning, So I do this:

```py
def create_keras_model():
    baseModel = tf.keras.models.load_model(path\to\model)
    headModel = baseModel.output
    model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(headModel)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=model_output)
    for layer in baseModel.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    return model

state = iterative_process.initialize()
keras_model = create_keras_model()
state = tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights(
    state,
    trainable_weights=[v.numpy() for v in keras_model.trainable_weights],
    non_trainable_weights=[
        v.numpy() for v in keras_model.non_trainable_weights
    ])

evaluation = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_fn)
```

And here is the training loop :

```py
for round_num in range(1, NUM_ROUNDS):
    state, _ = iterative_process.next(state, train_data)
    test_metrics = evaluation(state.model, test_data)
    print(test_metrics))
```

The problem is that test accuracy still constant and does not increase after all round  :

```py
round  1, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.8680933)])
round  2, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.836558)])
round  3, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.82953715)])
round  4, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.82713753)])
round  5, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.82613766)])
round  6, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.8256878)])
round  7, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.82548285)])
round  8, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.825384)])
round  9, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.67105263), ('loss', 0.825332)])
```

I would like to understand the reason, If there is another way to do this? Knowing that my dataset is an image dataset with 3 class.

Comment: It seems like there maybe a syntax error in the model definition, `model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)` perhaps needs to be called on `headModel` from the line above it? Could we include the code for the `evaluation()` function in the question? This can help source better answers.

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett the question is edited, please can you tell us from what can be the problem ?